# Why can't I enable swap on startup?

Tags: swap

I made I swap partition with GParted and it works great, since my computer only has 2 GB of memory. But, every time I boot up, I have to execute sudo swapon /dev/sda1 until it enables. How can I set it up so it enables automatically. I am have only been using Ubuntu for three months, so you might have to spell things out for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Swap partitions are enabled either:

- on boot if they're listed in `/etc/fstab`
- when you run `swapon /dev/<device>`
- or when you run `swapon -a`, given that you have some swap devices configured in fstab.

Run:

```
grep swap /etc/fstab
```

If there's no output, you don't have a swap partition added to /etc/fstab.

If your swap partition is i.e. /dev/sda1 add

```
/dev/sda1 none swap sw 0 0
```

to the end of your `/etc/fstab` file and run `swapon -a`.

Verify that your partition is in use as a swap via

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

Comment: I, instead, ran `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and added the UUID as my swap is a partition `UUID=<the uuid> none swap sw 0 0`