# Swap partition not working

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, swap

Ubuntu gives me an error on boot saying it can't find my Swap partition.

I ran **free -m** and this was the result. It says I don't have any swap memory. I can't post any images but these were the results.

**MEM**: total(3692) used(2357) free(1334) shared (248) buffers(84) cached(908)

**-/+ buffers/cache**: used(1364) free(2357)

**Swap**: used(0) free(0) shared(0)

I tried to see if a swap partition exists on my hard drive. It does. I have allotted 60 GB to Ubuntu.

**1st sub-partition**
device: /dev/sda5

partition type: Linux

contents: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root

**2nd sub partition**
device: /dev/sda6

partition type: Linux Swap

contents: unknown

**Can anyone help?**

Answer (score 0):

Please check out my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571516/why-cant-i-enable-swap-on-startup/571528#571528). There are steps to check which swap partitions are in use and instructions on making the OS use them.

Comment: Running "grep swap /etc/fstab" give me 
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=60449995-e48e-4b1d-ad7b-25269c4aca95 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

I added /dev/sda6 none swap sw 0 0 to /etc/fstab.
On running swapon -a, I get 
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
swapon: /dev/sda6: open failed: Permission denied

On running sudo swapon -a, I get
swapon: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: stat failed: No such file or directory
swapon: /dev/sda6: read swap header failed: Invalid argument

Can you help?